# "Failed to push application, host taken" error even after giving permission

Tags: ibm-cloud

My teammate is seeing a "Failed to push application, host taken" error even after I have added her as a user on the domain I have created.

One thing I noticed is that the Roles field for the domain shows only Manager, Auditor and Billing Manager. I have enabled all of those.

I have added my teammate as a Developer in the particular "Space" where the app runs.

Comment: See this post additionally, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647589/new-to-bluemix-getting-error-the-host-is-taken-for-new-app.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can only use the same url (host and domain) connected to two different apps in the same space.  In this case, you will get round robin between the two apps.  If you want the team mate to replace the existing app, she needs to push her app to the same app name and the same space as your original app

Comment: I believe we are doing this. Let me check.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a unique word at the end of your application name. By default, the application name becomes the first part of the url - which needs to be globally unique. .mybluemix.net

Comment: Actually we are both working on the same project, so we need to deploy to the same URL. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @pramodbiligiri Use the same application name in the manifest or push command.

Comment: Can you confirm both of you are in the same org and space? In the Bluemix console, both of you should be able to see the application. and the output of the "cf target" command should point to the same org and space.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please make sure she is logged into the same space as the existing app.