# Error BXNUI2032E: The host is taken -- Occurs while creating a Java Liberty project in IBM Bluemix

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am using the Java DB Web Starter boilerplate in IBM Bluemix. When I use it to create an app called SentimentAnalysisAPP, create fails with this error:

BXNUI2032E: An error occurred when contacting Cloud Foundry to create a resource. Resource: routes. Cloud Foundry message: "The host is taken: SentimentAnalysisAPP." See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try naming your application something else. Bluemix will try to auto create the URL for your app based on what you type into the name of the app.

SentimentAnalysisAPP.mybluemix.net is already in use.

Pick a name that is more unique, like SentimentAnalysisPDHTest.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I did the same & project get created

Comment: @PDH, if this fixed the problem, you should accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

That means the URL "SentimentAnalysisAPP.mybluemix.net" has been taken by someone else.

You need to create a unique host for it.

If you are running cf cli version 6.4 or above, you can use --random-route to let system generate one for you. eg. 
cf push SentimentAnalysisAPP --random-route

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ram Vennam said, the problem is that your app name (in this case, SentimentAnalysisAPP) is not unique, that another Bluemix user is already using that app name and URL.

This question is fairly common and has been answered before. You need to search for "BXNUI2032E" and "the host is taken". Then you'll find answers like these:

- [New To Bluemix, getting error “The host is taken” for new app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647589/new-to-bluemix-getting-error-the-host-is-taken-for-new-app)
- [I am not able to create a application with boiler plate Java Cloudant Web Starter getting error from cloud foundry](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/179902/i-am-not-able-to-create-a-application-with-boiler.html)
- [Failed Create the host name for apps mobile cloud](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27085/failed-create-the-host-name-for-apps-mobile-cloud.html)